# Using javascript __proto__ in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

Hi I have this two objects in javascript

```
var john = { firstname: 'John', lastname: 'Smith' }

var jane = { firstname: 'Jane' }
```

doing this:

```
jane.__proto__ = john;
```

I can access to jane's properties and also john's properties

If `__proto__` is not supported in IE8 for example, what's the equivalent to write this:

```
jane.__proto__ = john;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

There is no equivalent or standard mechanism in IE. (The [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) property in Firefox is *non-standard* extension as is *not specified* in the ECMAScript standards.)

The [[prototype]] object can *only* be specified by setting the `prototype` property upon the function-object which acts as the constructor *before* the construction of a new object. The [[prototype]] can, however, be *mutated* later.

Anyway, here is a little example of specifying a [[prototype]] from an existing object. Note that the [[prototype]] assignment must be done *before* the new object is created. ECMAScript 5th edition introduces [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) which can do the following *and* shallow-clone an object.

```
function create (proto) {
    function f () {}
    f.prototype = proto
    return new f
}
var joe = create({})
var jane = create(joe)
joe.name = "joe"                   // modifies object used as jane's [[prototype]]
jane.constructor.prototype === joe // true
jane.__proto__ === joe             // true  -- in Firefox, but not IE
jane.name                          // "joe" -- through [[prototype]]
jane.constructor.prototype = {}    // does NOT re-assign jane's [[prototype]]
jane.name                          // "joe" -- see above
```

Comment: `__proto__` is standard, and was know to be in future standard when this answer was made, and as such was implemented by other browsers at the time.  A more accurate answer will be that IE 8 was being conservative and/or lagging behind on the standard front, instead of representing a known future standard as non-standard.

Answer (score 0):

`__proto__` currently is not an standard use.

Following the ECMAScript standard, the notation someObject.[[Prototype]] is used to designate the prototype of someObject. Since ECMAScript 5, the [[Prototype]] is accessed using the accessors `Object.getPrototypeOf()` and `Object.setPrototypeOf()`.

So you could use `getPrototypeOf()` to access.

As in chrome,

```
> Object.getPrototypeOf(Object) === Object.__proto__
< true
```