# __proto__ in IE8 using ko

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, internet-explorer-8

I am searching for a safe way to make an existing function an `instanceof` another function.

I read here that `__proto__` is not supported by IE8: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12431941/665261

I read that knockout js supports IE8: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/browser-support.html

I found knockout using `__proto__`: https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/241c26ca82e6e4b3eaee39e3dc0a92f85bc1df0c/src/utils.js#L21

How can it be that knockout uses `__proto__` and yet works on IE8?

Comment: *"I am searching for a safe way to make an existing function an instance of another function."* Functions are instances of `Function`. Are you trying to make an **object** look like it's an instance created by a different constructor function? Sounds like an X/Y issue to me.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder not X/Y. Whilst searching more broadly for a better understanding of prototypal inheritance, I was led to this specific question. Thanks for your prompt and enlightening response!

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Yeah, sometimes we investigate tech just to give ourselves the knowledge of more tools. In that vein, I'm sure you found it, but ideally rather than `__proto__` (which is a browser-only hack), where possible use [`Reflect.setPrototypeOf`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-reflect.setprototypeof) or [`Object.setPrototypeOf`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object.setprototypeof). (Well, actually, where possible avoid changing the prototype of an existing object...)

Comment: (Link for [`__proto__`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object.prototype.__proto__) just for completeness. Wouldn't fit in the previous comment and SO doesn't allow URL-shorteners...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can it be that knockout uses `__proto__` and yet works on IE8?

Because it detects whether `__proto__` is supported by the browser it's running on and only uses it if it's supported.

Just a couple of lines after the one you linked to you'll find:

> ```
> var canSetPrototype = ({ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array);
> ```

...and further down when defining an object:

> ```
> setPrototypeOfOrExtend: canSetPrototype ? setPrototypeOf : extend,
> ```

Then KO uses `setPrototypeOfOrExtend` depending on whether `__proto__` is  supported.